# C#: How to check internet access in PCL project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, webclient

I'm trying to check for an internet connection in a PCL project that is used by a Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects. I'm gathering from my research that WebClient can't be used in a PCL, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution that doesn't use WebClient. Here's the code I'd like to use:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone know of a good solution that is similarly simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the Connectivity plugin from James Montemagno:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin

You install this, then call:

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected
```

from your PCL. You can even subscribe to an event to see when connectivity changes:

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += <handler>
```

This works on iOS and Android.

Comment: I get this Unhandled Exception when I try to implement the plugin in the PCL:

"System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation." I'm followed that advice and just implemented it separately in each platform-specific project, and that's working.

Comment: Glad it's working, and don't thank me - thank James Montemagno - his plugins are fantastic!

Comment: I'll have to check out some of his other stuff!

Comment: Pretty much if you want a cross platform solution to something, James will have already written a plugin for it!

Comment: CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected if u r connected to a wireless network but the internet is lost  it will stay show u that its connected.
maybe need additional dependency services

Comment: @Jonathan i am having the same issue. Could you please guide me how to resolve it?

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi - you are getting the NotImplementException? You need to add the package to ALL the projects in your app, the core PCL/netstandard as well as all the app projects.